# scale_colour_grey() doesn't permit legend label overwrite, shows both old and new instead

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried for 2 hours to solve this probably easy problem. This may not be a duplicate - since **I cannot find a question/answer about the situation in which shape and colour are used in combination with scale_colour_grey to overwrite legend labels**.

I also know the code is more than suboptimal (I am using it for a template for various different graphics) and will gladly accept other improvements, but I would like to solve the problem at hand:

I am trying to generate the graph which is outputed by the code below, trying to overwrite the labels with `labels=c("Podemos-PCE/IU", "Podemos-PSOE", "PSOE-PCE/IU")`. As soon as scale_colour_grey() is applied, my legend is split and I cannot overwrite it. Instead, it puts the new labels next to the old ones.

The data:

```
compBtwLeftParties <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16344, 16526, 16709, 16892, 
16983, 17167, 17348, 17532, 17713, 17805, 17897, 16344, 16526, 
16709, 16892, 16983, 17167, 17348, 17532, 17713, 17805, 17897, 
3103, 3804, 4838, 5448, 5660, 5813, 5903, 5995, 6360, 6574, 6665, 
6940, 7244, 7609, 7821, 8552, 8797, 9100, 9282, 9556, 10347, 
10773, 10988, 11931, 12570, 12784, 13118, 13239, 13899, 14153, 
14365, 14426, 14518, 14669, 14791, 15065, 15248, 15371, 15522, 
15614, 15887, 16161, 16344, 16526, 16709, 16892, 16983, 17167, 
17348, 17532, 17713, 17805, 17897), class = "Date"), party = c("PODEMOSPSOE", 
"PODEMOSPSOE", "PODEMOSPSOE", "PODEMOSPSOE", "PODEMOSPSOE", "PODEMOSPSOE", 
"PODEMOSPSOE", "PODEMOSPSOE", "PODEMOSPSOE", "PODEMOSPSOE", "PODEMOSPSOE", 
"PODEMOSPCEIU", "PODEMOSPCEIU", "PODEMOSPCEIU", "PODEMOSPCEIU", 
"PODEMOSPCEIU", "PODEMOSPCEIU", "PODEMOSPCEIU", "PODEMOSPCEIU", 
"PODEMOSPCEIU", "PODEMOSPCEIU", "PODEMOSPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU", 
"PSOEPCEIU", "PSOEPCEIU"), competition = c(7.82, 7.83, 7.85, 
7.72, 7.6, 7.44, 7.88, 7.69, 8.01, 8.01, 8, 9.76, 9.69, 9.68, 
9.91, 9.96, 9.94, 9.93, 9.92, 9.86, 9.88, 9.9, 8.36, 8.64, 8.66, 
8.54, 8.22, 8.29, 8.24, 8.22, 8.13, 8.13, 8.14, 8.09, 7.97, 8.07, 
8.02, 8.02, 7.63, 7.74, 7.86, 8, 8.18, 8.15, 8.09, 8.04, 8.33, 
8.29, 8.35, 8.41, 8.36, 8.35, 8.36, 8.44, 8.33, 8.39, 8.42, 8.33, 
8.24, 8.28, 8.32, 8.19, 8.25, 8.17, 8.06, 8.14, 8.17, 7.81, 7.56, 
7.38, 7.81, 7.61, 7.87, 7.89, 7.9), mean1 = c(8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333, 
8.34293333333333, 8.34293333333333), sd1 = c(0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499, 
0.680168162213499, 0.680168162213499), min1 = c(7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983, 
7.66276517111983, 7.66276517111983), max1 = c(9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683, 
9.02310149554683, 9.02310149554683)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -75L))
```

The code:

```
compBtwLeftParties%>%
  filter(!is.na(competition))%>%
ggplot(aes(date, competition, shape=party, colour=party)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point() + theme_hc() +
  scale_colour_grey(name="", labels=c("Podemos-PCE/IU", "Podemos-PSOE", "PSOE-PCE/IU"), start = .0, end = .0, aesthetics = c("colour"))  +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min1, ymax=max1, x=date), fill = "grey70",alpha=.1, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
    labs(title="Gr. 9: Wettbewerb Linksparteien") + 
    theme(text=element_text(size=12, family = "Times New Roman"),
        title=element_text(size=12),
        legend.position="bottom", 
        legend.margin = margin(t = -.3, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0, unit = "cm"),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(.1, "cm"),
        legend.background= element_rect(fill="transparent",colour=NA),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.key.size = unit(.3, "cm"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_text(size=12))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the following line of code:
`scale_shape_manual(name="", labels=c("Podemos-PCE/IU", "Podemos-PSOE", "PSOE-PCE/IU"), values=0:2)`, which made the legend for shape identical to that for colour (in this case scale_colour_grey()).

```
compBtwLeftParties%>%
  filter(!is.na(competition))%>%
ggplot(aes(date, competition, shape=party, colour=party)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_hc() +
  scale_colour_grey(name="", labels=c("Podemos-PCE/IU", "Podemos-PSOE", "PSOE-PCE/IU"), start=.0, end=.0)  +
  scale_shape_manual(name="", labels=c("Podemos-PCE/IU", "Podemos-PSOE", "PSOE-PCE/IU"), values=0:2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min1, ymax=max1, x=date), fill = "grey70",alpha=.1, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
    labs(title="Gr. 9: Wettbewerb Linksparteien") + 
    theme(text=element_text(size=12, family = "Times New Roman"),
        title=element_text(size=12),
        legend.position="bottom", 
        legend.margin = margin(t = -.3, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0, unit = "cm"),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(.1, "cm"),
        legend.background= element_rect(fill="transparent",colour=NA),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.key.size = unit(.3, "cm"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_text(size=12))
```